# Code Coverage of sahi files in ANT

Tags: ant, code-coverage, sahi

I have a test suite containing sahi files ( Sahi - web browser Automation test tool). I want to run code coverage for this suite using ANT. I am new to sahi & unable to find good documentation to integrate sahi with ANT using emma, jacoco or cobertura.
Anybody who has worked with such scenario can help here?

Comment: This is integration of sahi with jenkins which i have done already. I am actually looking for the code coverage part. Any info on that?

Comment: Are you looking for the code coverage of your sahi scripts or for your application? Because code coverage for application makes sense. Code coverage for Sahi scripts, not so much.

Comment: I want to run code coverage for sahi scripts which are .js files so is it possible to user jacoco or any other tool to give code coverage for such scripts?? Can it work with sonar?